# Exception calling “ImportBacPac” with “2” argument(s): “Could not import package”

Tags: powershell, bacpac

I know this has been asked earlier, but I could not see any answer to this hence posting again.

As part of PS(ver 4.0) importbacpac  I am hitting the following error intermittently
Exception calling "ImportBacPac" with "2" argument(s): "Could not import package." And the exception is “Invalid Operation”.
The machine has sql 2014 and the bacpac was exported on sql 2014 only, so there is no mismatch that way and we are using windows authentication for import. The thing is that the error is not consistent and happens at times only.
Any idea what could be going on here?

added code

```
function Perform-Restore([string]$DbName, [string]$connectionString, [string]$sqlserverVersion,       [string]$bacpacFilePath)
{
Load-DacFx -sqlserverVersion $sqlserverVersion

$dacServiceInstance = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices ($connectionString)

$bacpacPackageInstance = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($bacpacFilePath)

try
{
    **$dacServiceInstance.ImportBacpac($bacpacPackageInstance, $DbName)**
}
catch
{
    Throw "Restore Failed"
}
}

function Load-DacFx([string]$sqlserverVersion)
{
  $majorVersion = Get-SqlServerMajoreVersion -sqlServerVersion $sqlserverVersion

  $DacFxLocation = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SQL Server\$majorVersion\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"

try
{  
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($DacFxLocation) | Out-Null
}
catch
{
    Throw "$LocalizedData.DacFxInstallationError"
}
}
```

Comment: Please include your code. I can't help you from just the error message.

Comment: added code in the original post.

Comment: i have already posted the code,any ideas now?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to move the `Load-DacFx` function above `Perform-Restore` because when `Load-DacFx` is called the first time, the function hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: It is just defined later, but called from inside Perform-Restore,so I guess that is not the issue.

Comment: With some troubleshooting I have come to an almost certain conclusion that when I run this code at that point the SQL server service is not in "Running" state and hence the failure. The reason this happens is because I am running this piece of code as PS DSC as part of a test that provisions a fresh Azure VM on every run.

Comment: That would definitely explain it! Thanks for updating us.